# Google Firebase hits limit

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

We've got a notification from Google that we exceeded Google Analytics hits limit (10 million per month). And right now i'm looking for a free solving of the problem. So the question is - can Firebase be a solution? Has it some hits limit in free version? Or maybe there are other free ways to change the situation?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that you've hit this limit.  There's not much anyone here can do about this. Please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for free, personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

if ypu check the pricing page of Firebase you will see that Analytics and other usefull options are free .

https://firebase.google.com/pricing/